# how to store and retrieve url of photos in dynamodb from s3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'm working on storing many images in AWS S3.

I need to retrieve the URL from S3 and store it in DynamoDB.

I am not clear on how to do this via NodeJS. Can someone explain how it works with a Lambda function?

Comment: https://snowulf.com/2015/08/05/tutorial-aws-api-gateway-to-lambda-to-dynamodb/

Comment: Yup. Research people, read the docs before asking on the forums!

Comment: For a question, you must post the steps you have taken, code you have attempted, and errors you are experiencing.

Answer (score 5):

1. Be sure to have your S3 bucket all set up with whatever you need. Not sure why you want this but I'm going to assume you have it set up to be either private or public.

   - IF you have static hosting enabled, the url's in this will very
2. Navigate to Lambda and set up your function. Put in name, description, etc. but nothing in the code field (we'll get there)
3. Set up your ram and permissions (must have basic DynamoDB execution permission at *least*)
4. Now it'll load for a second, when its done - paste in this code

   ```
   const
       AWS = require( 'aws-sdk' );

   AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

   exports.handler = function( event, context ) {

       var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB(),
           bucket = event.Records[ 0 ].s3.bucket.name,
           key = event.Records[ 0 ].s3.object.key,
           params = {
               TableName: '[table]',
               Item: {
                   hash: '[hash]',
                   range: '[range]',
                   s3key: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/' + bucket + '/' + key
               }
           };

       console.log( '\n\n{\n    Bucket: ' + bucket + ',\n    Key: ' + key + ',\n    URL: ' + params.Item.s3key + '\n}\n' );

       ddb.put( params, function( err, data ) {

           // respond with whatever you want
           context.succeed( ( err ) ? JSON.stringify( err, null, 2 ) : JSON.stringify( data, null, 2 ) );

       } );

   };
   ```

Example: [image: icon] - https://s3.amazonaws.com/cerenity/SOResources/favicon.ico

**Update:** [@agl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4346725/agl) reminded me, if you do not use the "US-Standard" region, the specified region will be: `https://s3-[here].amazonaws.com/`

5. Fill in your information for table, hash, range, etc.
6. Go to `Actions` => `Configure test event` => `Sample event template` => `S3 Put` and you should see:

   ```
   {
       "Records": [
           {
               "eventVersion": "2.0",
               "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
               "requestParameters": {
                   "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
               },
               "s3": {
                   "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
                   "object": {
                       "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
                       "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901",
                       "key": "HappyFace.jpg",
                       "size": 1024
                   },
                   "bucket": {
                       "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
                       "name": "sourcebucket",
                       "ownerIdentity": {
                           "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
                       }
                   },
                   "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
               },
               "responseElements": {
                   "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH",
                   "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789"
               },
               "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
               "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
               "userIdentity": {
                   "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
               },
               "eventSource": "aws:s3"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
7. Now run your tests and you *should* see a record in your database - If not, continue editing your database params till you get them correct

   - Be sure all your permissions are set for the role assigned to this Lambda function
8. Once it works, go to the `Event sources` tab at the top and select `+ Add event source` => `Event source type` => `S3`
9. A menu requesting S3-like info should appear. Put in the bucket you want, prefix, suffix, whatever - then select `Event type` => `Object Created` and either `(All)` or one of the methods listed

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Lambda function that will be invoked by a [S3 put event](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html). A Lambda function grabs JSON with the `event` details (and corresponding `var`. The problem is the URL of object won't come in the JSON, but you can build the url with the JSON parameters. The url will be like this:

[https://s3-*region*.amazonaws.com/*bucket*/*key*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html)

You can insert this URL into DynamoDB with the [AWSSDK for NodeJS](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/). The URL format will be different in Virginia (US-Standard) region. Anyway, [HERE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) you have link for more information.

Then, create the event in your bucket in the S3 console or directly in Lambda console, upload a file and voila.

Regards

Comment: Not particularly detailed, but yes. This is a beginner user and needs the full walk through